Android's emulator command crashes with Segmentation fault on Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon
I have Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon running and installed Android studio including its emulator.
Now a lot of people run into all sorts of problems when trying to actually emulate a device, but for me the emulator command even crashes when I just want to display the help:
./emulator -help

yields:
[3326:3326:20240828,191915.586852:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:64] tag not found
[3326:3326:20240828,191915.587974:WARNING process_reader_linux.cc:144] no stack mapping
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

The respective journalctl -f looks like this:
Process 3324 (emulator) of user 1001 dumped core.
                                                
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator with build-id: 4fc738dc76d85942c37e0bb2f4098472223d8afe
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libprotobuf.so.32 without build-id.
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libglib2_linux-x86_64.so with build-id: 4dbed67c441c1aacd68825484729a0e97fbb1d9a
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-emu-base-logging.so with build-id: 445d7534bc1161b0704e8389cd9a91735544ba1f
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libc++.so.1 without build-id.
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-emu-agents.so with build-id: f0465a90155794889277a0e5b93b6cdd4696ec3e
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-emu-curl.so with build-id: e2184f4ff3fbc97aff738a3f5a6ad34a6c913733
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-emu-metrics.so with build-id: 8464276cb0dad741cbaa5327329df28f77387be4
                                                Found module /home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libandroid-emu-protos.so with build-id: 577111c450913ff1c224ae5fe41e69869558f9cd
                                                Found module linux-vdso.so.1 with build-id: 9b79168bfbd8aeae8ff8785c33d8386d7d9df1ad
                                                Found module libmd.so.0 with build-id: cd2d2f71b3967ebde30e2aa43b8eb63339020c06
                                                Found module libbsd.so.0 with build-id: 9a6c72469251e2feb63e175ef5cb944ce6e00df3
                                                Found module libXext.so.6 with build-id: 9fb1880e02dfa11a8c39cd1a170109de08302059
                                                Found module libXdmcp.so.6 with build-id: 6b60f99504aa1d3999ea02a14366d1a39d6c5dcf
                                                Found module libXau.so.6 with build-id: 7089b383cacbfc1760634a3be19a923e51fe3315
                                                Found module libstdc++.so.6 with build-id: e37fe1a879783838de78cbc8c80621fa685d58a2
                                                Found module libXi.so.6 with build-id: 8ff5a3ac871a90fd9d0a7917c61f748a41c6b5ee
                                                Found module libxcb.so.1 with build-id: 1bef862a339557aa16c34c7a4b27f8f3aea90517
                                                Found module ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with build-id: 4186944c50f8a32b47d74931e3f512b811813b64
                                                Found module libc.so.6 with build-id: 490fef8403240c91833978d494d39e537409b92e
                                                Found module libgcc_s.so.1 with build-id: e3a44e0da9c6e835d293ed8fd2882b4c4a87130c
                                                Found module libm.so.6 with build-id: a508ec5d8bf12fb7fd08204e0f87518e5cd0b102
                                                Found module libpthread.so.0 with build-id: 81f46d553e2f7c999e43c3eede73a822bc8d5d93
                                                Found module librt.so.1 with build-id: fa3a0740c79389792000620954a14ee7c2126aa0
                                                Found module libdl.so.2 with build-id: 6f6fe1a24b7b981e11c9a3373b806d3496d4d9d4
                                                Found module libX11.so.6 with build-id: 37a5d7bbb78e3a99ea8376a7c80ea0c62fe06494
                                                Found module libAppProtection.so with build-id: fd8d0810c960df183049686bfa56f88d1f4a481d
                                                Stack trace of thread 3324:
                                                #0  0x00007f5ebd2d5e57 _int_malloc (libc.so.6 + 0xa3e57)
                                                #1  0x00007f5ebd2d7262 __GI___libc_malloc (libc.so.6 + 0xa5262)
                                                #2  0x00007f5ebda110e5 n/a (/home/arbeit/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libc++.so.1 + 0xb50e5)

To be honest none of these infos help me much, which of this can I actually use to find out what's wrong and fix it?
Another detail about this: the exact same installation of the emulator on the same Linux Mint installation used to work flawlessly and now it stopped, so I suspect this might have something to do with some update of Linux Mint or its libraries that happened in between.
I'd be grateful for any ideas on what to try to find out what's wrong here.

Just guessing: For me this kind of crash (same console output) was caused by Citrix AppProtection. It no longer occured after commenting out the respective entry in /etc/ld.so.preload.

I do actually have Citrix Workspace installed, good tip, I'll check, thanks!

That was it, thanks a lot!
